# What do the *-dev packages in the Linux package repositories actually contain?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, repository, package

My question is very basic, as is my knowledge right now.

I'm a long-time Linux user, but have only recently taken a major interest in programming. I see that many popular applications in the Ubuntu repositories have -dev packages (e.g. *pidgin-dev* in addition to *pidgin*). My question is this:

What is in these packages? How does downloading *pidgin-dev* help one to develop for Pidgin? Is it as simple as a dependency check for the tools necessary to create the plugins for the given application?

I was hoping there would be a substantial amount of documentation in the -dev packages, but if there is, I can't figure out how to access it. I'm thinking of something like a man-page, but useful for editing code.

Any and all advice more than welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are \*-devel packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358801/what-are-devel-packages)

Comment: devel is different from dev. (in term of string's value)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The `*-dev` packages most often contain the headers related to a library's interface. Next most common are package-config files (`*.pc`) describing build options and staticly linked libraries.

In general, if you want to know the contents of a package you have installed, `dpkg -L pkgname` will get you that. The `apt-file` program can tell you the same for any package in the repositories.

Note, also, that the answers by William Pursell and caf contain useful additional details. If you find their input helpful, do upvote it.

Comment: If you want to know the contents without installing, you can also use apt-get download, and then dpkg-deb -c

Comment: @Jeff The easier way to do that is with `apt-file list packagename`.

Answer (score 42):

(disclaimer: I'm familiar with Debian but not Ubuntu, so although it is almost certain that everything I write below applies, there's is a chance it's not.)

One more item in the `*-dev` package is the `/usr/lib/lib*.so` link.  The `libfoo0` package will install the file `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.0.0`, while `libfoo-dev` installs the links `/usr/lib/libfoo.so.0` and `/usr/lib/libfoo.so`.  This is the mechanism that allows you to have `libfoo0` and `libfoo1` installed simultaneously, so that software requiring the old library can co-exist on the box with software using the new library.  When you install `libfoo-dev`, any software that is compiled will follow the `*.so` link and link against the version of the library referenced by that link.

Answer (score 22):

The -dev packages usually contain C header files and statically compiled versions of library files (.a extension).  Sometimes they contain additional documentation and examples, or even helper applications.

Answer (score 4):

This package contains the headers and other development files not included in the main pidgin package. Install -dev if you wish to compile your own plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I think both caf's and William's answer are correct while missing the most important notion -
You CANNOT compile your code over runtime libraries. They are the bear minimum so that your code runs, aka solving runtime dependencies.  Almost exclusively *.so files.
Usually what happens is that you develop your program using development libraries, as you have the header file, static libraries (*.a), documentations and even some source files as examples for binary compilation.  These files take more storage and offer no value during runtime.
I am an SDK developer so these semantics are very important when trying to create a modular solution for users.