# What are *-devel packages?

Tags: c

What is the utility of devel packages like "libgtk+-devel" or "python-devel" etc.? Do they contain source of the library? How is it different from non-devel packages like libgtk+?

Comment: It's not worth opening another answer, but in addition to existing answers, I should emphasize that packagers try to put in a non-devel package such as `libgtk+` the minimum footprint necessary to run (as opposed to "develop") gtk+ programs. That means only dynamic libraries and configuration files. Everything else goes in the complementary `-devel` package.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The `*-devel` packages (usually called `*-dev` in Debian-based distributions) are usually all the files necessary to compile code against a given library.

For running an application using the library `libfoo` only the actualy shared library file (`*.so.*`, for example `libfoo.so.1.0`) are needed (plus possibly some data files and some version-specific symlinks).

When you actually want to compile a C application that uses that library you'll need the header files (`*.h`, for example `foo.h`) that describe the interface of that application as well as a version-less symlink to the shared library (`*.so`, for example `libfoo.so` -> `libfoo.so.1.0`). Those are usually bundled in the `*-devel` packages.

Sometimes the `*-devel` packages also include statically compiled versions of the libraries (`*.a`, for example `libfoo.a`) in case you want to build a complete stand-alone application that doesn't depend on dynamic libraries at all.

Other languages (such as Java, Python, ...) use a different way of noting the API of a library (effectively including all the necessary information in the actual library) and thus usually need no separate `*-devel` packages (except maybe for documentation and additional tools).

Comment: Almost. the `.so` file is in the -devel package; the normal shared library goes by `.so.*`, since it includes a SONAME. The `.so` file is used by the linker, and the `.so.*` library is used at runtime.

Comment: so basically you need the *devel libs of the application in question if it's a dependency of another application, because you need to expose the interface?

Comment: @ohhh: no. You only need those packages if you *compile* something that needs that library. If one package *uses* that library then you don't need the `-devel` package. In other words: most normal users will never need the `-devel` package, but developers might.

Answer (score 11):

They usually contain necessary headers and libraries. For example, python-devel will provide the Python headers and libraries that you need if you want to embed the Python interpreter in your own application. Some additional tools and documentation are included, too (e.g. a developer manual or code examples).

Comment: Are tools such as pyinstaller an example of using this? Because AFAIK freezers embed a Python interpreter in the bundle they create as well which is just what you have said here.