# Building both devel and normal version of a RPM package

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I have a library from which I'd like to create two RPM packages.

While I found several links on how to create a basic RPM package, I can't find how to create a `devel` package (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358801/what-are-devel-packages) if you wonder what a `devel` package is).

What do I have to do to generate both `devel` and `non-devel` versions of my RPM package ?

Thanks.

Comment: Great question - I can't believe how hard it is to find info on the web about how to build a -devel package.

Comment: @gareth_bowles I was surprised as well. It seems likes the *few* guys who are doing `devel` packages want to keep their secrets !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Read this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Docs/Drafts/BuildingPackagesGuide#Case_Study:_OpenEXR).

Answer (score 6):

I found [an example](http://kmymoney2.sourceforge.net/phb/rpm-example.html) of a `.spec` file which generates both `devel` and `non-devel` packages.

It seems you can create one (or several) *sub-package(s)* inside a package, appending `devel` (or whatever name you want to) after the `%files` directive.

Below is an extract from the example I posted:

```
Name:      kmymoney
Summary:   The Personal Finances Manager for KDE.
Version:   0.8
Release:   1.%{disttag}%{distver}
License:   GPL
Packager:  %packer
Group:     Productivity/Office/Finance
Source0:   %{name}2-%version.tar.bz2
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}2-%{version}-%{release}-build
BuildRequires: kdebase3-devel
Prereq: /sbin/ldconfig

%description
Description goes here...

%package devel
#Requires:
Summary: KMyMoney development files
Group: Productivity/Office/Finance
Provides: kmymoney-devel

%description devel
This package contains necessary header files for KMyMoney development.

... more to go here ...

%files
... some files ...

%files devel
... the devel files ...
```

Note the `devel` suffixes.