# How do I install the OpenSSL libraries on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, installation, openssl

I'm trying to build some code on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS that uses OpenSSL 1.0.0.  When I run make, it invokes g++ with the "-lssl" option.  The source includes:

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
```

I ran:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

But I guess the openssl package doesn't include the library.  I get these errors on make:

```
foo.cpp:21:25: error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
foo.cpp:22:28: error: openssl/buffer.h: No such file or directory
foo.cpp:23:25: error: openssl/des.h: No such file or directory
foo.cpp:24:25: error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
foo.cpp:25:25: error: openssl/pem.h: No such file or directory
foo.cpp:26:25: error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory
```

How do I install the OpenSSL C++ library on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

I did a `man g++` and (under "Options for Linking") for the -l option it states: " The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library..." and "The directories searched include several standard system directories..."  What are those standard system directories?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but answered by [What are *-devel packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358801/what-are-devel-packages).

Comment: You're right about the `-dev` naming convention. You might also use the `synaptic` package manager to list all packages whose names contain libssl - browsing that list and their descriptions would likely give you the clue.

Comment: I know this question is quite dead by now but since I recently found it I figure someone else might too.

If you want to list all packages that are similar to a certain name, I like to use >aptitude search <STRING>

It does not require root privilege level to run a search.

Comment: just to add to Evan's statement, recent versions of Ubuntu are coming without the aptitude command available. apt-cache search <packname> works the same way (almost) now.

Comment: In answer to your update, you could do `apt-cache search package-name`

Answer (score 757, accepted):

You want to install the development package, which is libssl-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: But this is not the version he wanted (1.0.0), which is not packaged for 10.04.  See this answer for 1.0.0:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153114/how-do-i-install-and-build-against-openssl-1-0-0-on-ubuntu

Comment: Ah, good call.  I only noticed at the time that he was trying to use the development libraries but wasn't installing the -dev package.  I didn't even notice the version number.

Comment: This is the right reference here: http://www.technologyskill.ga/install-openssl-manually-on-linux/ or https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/ libraries and header files are found under the same directory after installation: /usr/local/ssl

Comment: `apt install` for new dist ubuntu

Comment: Can this be installed on a specified directory? Or how can I find out where openssl is located in my system?

Comment: @GeorgeSp you can see the list of files using `apt-file list libssl-dev` command, or here https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libssl-dev/filelist
If you want to build the library yourself, please refer to one of below answers, e.g. from Mann (pay attention to step 3).

Comment: @ɛIc_ↄIз Can I create a portable directory of the library if I copy all the output from "apt-file list libssl-dev" in another directory and add it to my project? This is my main goal here, if you can suggest another way to do it, please share.

Comment: @GeorgeSp I think so, but it's still more "natural" to build them in a custom directory using this instruction https://stackoverflow.com/a/49578644/7315276

Comment: Worth pointing out that with Ubuntu (WSL on Windows)- I had to restart WSL in order for my build process to pick openssl up.

Answer (score 66):

Run:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 30):

All of these answers are very outdated and from when the package was still being developed. You can now just use the "normal" command listed below:

```
sudo apt install openssl
```

Edit: OP's question is poorly worded... after all, OpenSSL is a library itself, so I read his question too quickly before answering. The command above installs "normal" OpenSSL.

Toward the bottom of his question he mentions that `make` fails, suggesting he is compiling the package manually. And yes, even if you [download the TAR ball](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl), it will include all of the `openssl` and `libssl` files, which you can then `make` from.

What OP is really asking for is the **OpenSSL Development Library**, in which case you can first install OpenSSL using the above command, and then run this afterwards:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

More info: https://linuxtect.com/how-to-install-openssl-libraries-on-ubuntu-debian-mint/

Comment: If this is the answer that puts me 1000+ karma, I'm gonna lol

Comment: its a wrong answer, btw

Comment: @Nulik I've added more context and clarification, thanks.

Comment: for windows there are some way to do it?

Answer (score 22):

I found a detailed solution here: [Install OpenSSL Manually On Linux](http://www.technologyskill.ga/install-openssl-manually-on-linux/)

*From the blog post...:*

> Steps to download, compile, and install are as follows (I'm installing version 1.0.1g below; please replace "1.0.1g" with your version number):
>
> **Step – 1 : Downloading OpenSSL:**
>
> Run the command as below :
>
> `$ wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz`
>
> Also, download the MD5 hash to verify the integrity of the downloaded file for just varifacation purpose. In the same folder where you have downloaded the OpenSSL file from the website :
>
> `$ wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz.md5`
>   `$ md5sum openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz`
>   `$ cat openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz.md5`
>
> **Step – 2 : Extract files from the downloaded package:**
>
> `$ tar -xvzf openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz`
>
> Now, enter the directory where the package is extracted like here is openssl-1.0.1g
>
> `$ cd openssl-1.0.1g`
>
> **Step – 3 : Configuration OpenSSL**
>
> Run below command with optional condition to set prefix and directory where you want to copy files and folder.
>
> `$ ./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl`
>
> You can replace “/usr/local/openssl” with the directory path where you want to copy the files and folders. But make sure while doing this steps check for any error message on terminal.
>
> **Step – 4 : Compiling OpenSSL**
>
> To compile openssl you will need to run 2 command : make, make install as below :
>
> `$ make`
>
> Note: check for any error message for verification purpose.
>
> **Step -5 : Installing OpenSSL:**
>
> `$ sudo make install`
>
> Or without sudo,
>
> `$ make install`
>
> That’s it. OpenSSL has been successfully installed. You can run the version command to see if it worked or not as below :
>
> `$ /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl version`
>
> `OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014`

Comment: For completeness you should include the PGP signature verification to ensure that the files signature is valid. As in https://gnupg.org/download/integrity_check.html and https://www.openoffice.org/download/checksums.html#pgp_linux

Comment: `wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.0.7.tar.gz` for latest openssl release as of Dec. 2022

Answer (score 19):

> How could I have figured that out for
>   myself (other than asking this
>   question here)? Can I somehow tell
>   apt-get to list all packages, and grep
>   for ssl? Or do I need to know the
>   "lib*-dev" naming convention?

If you're linking with `-lfoo` then the library is likely `libfoo.so`.  The library itself is probably part of the `libfoo` package, and the headers are in the `libfoo-dev` package as you've discovered.

Some people use the GUI "synaptic" app (`sudo synaptic`) to (locate and) install packages, but I prefer to use the command line.  One thing that makes it easier to find the right package from the command line is the fact that `apt-get` supports bash completion.

Try typing `sudo apt-get install libssl` and then hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to see a list of matching package names (which can help when you need to select the correct version of a package that has multiple versions or other variations available).

Bash completion is actually very useful... for example, you can also get a list of commands that `apt-get` supports by typing `sudo apt-get` and then hitting <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: Ubuntu could ease the pain for folks since its been a problem for years. They *could* alias `openssl-dev` to `libssl-dev` but they choose not to.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to install openssl library from source code on Ubuntu, follows steps below, here `WORKDIR` is your working directory:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
cd WORKDIR
git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
cd openssl
./config
make
sudo make install
# Open file /etc/ld.so.conf, add a new line: "/usr/local/lib" at EOF
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the `openssl-devel` package.
At least I think it's `-devel` on Ubuntu.  Might be `-dev`.  It's one of the two.

Comment: Both `sudo apt-get install openssl-dev` and `sudo apt-get install openssl-devel` return "E: Couldn't find package..."

Comment: Apparently it's libssl-dev as the others have said.  I don't use Ubuntu, so I'm not familiar with the package names.

Comment: Openssl-devel was what I needed for CentOS 6.  `sudo yum install openssl-devel*`

Comment: Let's be honest: this naming sucks :)

Comment: well, this naming sucks :) - but still it is the best naming standard we can have... but someone really *SHOULD* finally start *teaching* this at school subject "basics of IT"  in ALL schools in the world.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, when on Debian or Ubuntu and you're missing a development file (or any other file for that matter), use `apt-file` to figure out which package provides that file:

```
~ apt-file search openssl/bio.h
android-libboringssl-dev: /usr/include/android/openssl/bio.h
libssl-dev: /usr/include/openssl/bio.h
libwolfssl-dev: /usr/include/cyassl/openssl/bio.h
libwolfssl-dev: /usr/include/wolfssl/openssl/bio.h
```

A quick glance at each of the packages that are returned by the command, using `apt show` will tell you which among the packages is the one you're looking for:

```
~ apt show libssl-dev
Package: libssl-dev
Version: 1.1.1d-2
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Source: openssl
Maintainer: Debian OpenSSL Team <pkg-openssl-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 8,095 kB
Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1d-2)
Suggests: libssl-doc
Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev
Homepage: https://www.openssl.org/
Tag: devel::lang:c, devel::library, implemented-in::TODO, implemented-in::c,
 protocol::ssl, role::devel-lib, security::cryptography
Download-Size: 1,797 kB
APT-Sources: http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
Description: Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
 This package is part of the OpenSSL project's implementation of the SSL
 and TLS cryptographic protocols for secure communication over the
 Internet.
 .
 It contains development libraries, header files, and manpages for libssl
 and libcrypto.

N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the official website and download the source code for the version you need
2. Then unzip the update package and execute the following command

   ```
   ./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ssl/lib shared
   ```

Because the default is to generate only static libraries, if you want dynamic libraries, add the **"shared"** option

3. `make && make install`

Comment: Every time you `make install`, one kitten dies... It's better to use `checkinstall`, if you're not satisfied with packages you have in repos.

Answer (score -3):

`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`