# C - Compiling problems with OpenSSL header files on Ubuntu v12.10

Tags: c, ubuntu, compiler-errors, openssl

I’m trying to compile the following C code in Eclipse CDT (v1.2.0.201212170456) on Ubuntu v12.10 32-bit.

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

My compiler is arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Sourcery G++ Lite 2010q1-202) 4.4.1.  I’ve set the path to the openssl folder, which is in /usr/include.  When I press F3 on the `#include` line, Eclipse CDT opens the bio.h file.  When I compile the code, I get about 500 errors such as the following:

```
expected ';' before 'int' line 301, external location: /usr/include/openssl/bio.h
```

`int (*bwrite)(BIO *, const char *, int);` <-- Line 300 in bio.h

`int (*bread)(BIO *, char *, int);` <-- Line 301 in bio.h

or

```
expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token line 234, external location: /usr/include/openssl/bio.h
```

`void BIO_set_flags(BIO *b, int flags);` <-- Line 233 in bio.h

`int  BIO_test_flags(const BIO *b, int flags);` <-- Line 234 in bio.h

I have both libssl and libssl-dev installed.  I'm really at a loss as to what could be the cause.  Please help!

From CDT's console output:

> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -I/usr/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -v -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.c"

Comment: Looks like BIO type is undefined at this point?

Comment: The same code compiles fine in VS2010 (I'm using Windows 7).  I don't see how BIO is undefined.  It's defined in bio.h.

Comment: If `openssl/bio.h` is under the standard `/usr/include` there should have been no need to explicitly set it. You might like to show us Eclipse's compile command as printed to the console window.

Comment: If I remove the the standard /usr/include then Eclipse complains "Unresolved inclusion: <openssl/bio.h>".  Please see my post for my compiler command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I was able to solve the problems by following the instructions given by [SB.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263895/sb) in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153114/how-do-i-install-and-build-against-openssl-1-0-0-on-ubuntu).

As I’m statically linking to OpenSSL, I’ve copied the following files to my C project in Eclipse CDT.

- libcrypto.a
- libssl.a