# LiteSpeed Web Server and "error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries"

Tags: php, ubuntu, server, openssl, litespeed

I installed [LiteSpeed web server](https://www.litespeedtech.com/products/litespeed-web-server/overview) in Ubuntu server. I'm trying to compile php7.0.10 using lsws admin panel via browser. I installed libssl-dev,  libssl-ocaml, libssl-ocaml-dev, libsslcommon2, libsslcommon2-dev, cl-plus-ssl, but it is still not install, saying that 'Cannot find OpenSSL libraries', haw can i fix this?

```
**MAIN_STATUS** retrieved from /usr/local/lsws/phpbuild/buildphp_1478001484.6.progress
Start building PHP 7.0.10 with LSAPI
Configuring PHP build (2-3 minutes)
**ERROR** Could not configure PHP build
```

Log detail;

```
**LOG_DETAIL** retrieved from /usr/local/lsws/phpbuild/buildphp_1478001484.6.log

==============================================
Start building PHP 7.0.10 with LSAPI
==============================================
Sal Kas 1 14:58:48 +03 2016

Changing to build directory /usr/local/lsws/phpbuild/php-7.0.10
Configuring PHP build (2-3 minutes)
 ./configure '--prefix=/usr/local/lsws/lsphp7' '--with-mysqli' '--with-zlib' '--
with-gd' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvsh
m' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-iconv' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--enab
le-ftp' '--enable-zip' '--with-curl' '--enable-soap' '--enable-xml' '--enable-js
on' '--with-openssl' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-litespeed'
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking whether to enable runpaths... yes
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for bison version... invalid
configure: WARNING: This bison version is not supported for regeneration of the 
Zend/PHP parsers (found: none, min: 204, excluded: ).
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate
 PHP parsers.
checking whether to enable computed goto gcc extension with re2c... no
checking whether to force non-PIC code in shared modules... no
checking whether /dev/urandom exists... yes
checking whether /dev/arandom exists... no
checking for global register variables support... yes
checking for pthreads_cflags... -pthread
checking for pthreads_lib... 

[1mConfiguring SAPI modules[0;10m
checking for Apache 2.0 handler-module support via DSO through APXS... no
checking for setproctitle... no
checking sys/pstat.h usability... no
checking sys/pstat.h presence... no
checking for sys/pstat.h... no
checking for PS_STRINGS... no
checking for CLI build... yes
checking for embedded SAPI library support... no
checking for FPM build... no
checking for LiteSpeed support... yes
checking for phpdbg support... yes
checking for phpdbg web SAPI support... no
checking for phpdbg debug build... no
checking whether termios.h defines TIOCGWINSZ... no
checking whether sys/ioctl.h defines TIOCGWINSZ... yes
checking for CGI build... yes
checking for socklen_t in sys/socket.h... yes
checking for sun_len in sys/un.h... no
checking whether cross-process locking is required by accept()... no
checking for chosen SAPI module... none
checking for executable SAPI binaries...  cli litespeed phpdbg cgi

[1mRunning system checks[0;10m
checking for sendmail... no
checking whether system uses EBCDIC... no
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether writing to stdout works... This is the test message -- yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for socketpair... yes
checking for htonl... yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for gethostbyaddr... yes
checking for yp_get_default_domain... no
checking for __yp_get_default_domain... no
checking for yp_get_default_domain in -lnsl... yes
checking for dlopen... no
checking for __dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for sin in -lm... yes
checking for inet_aton... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking for ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h... no
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for alloca.h... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking for arpa/nameser.h... yes
checking for assert.h... yes
checking for crypt.h... yes
checking for dns.h... no
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for grp.h... yes
checking for ieeefp.h... no
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for monetary.h... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking for pwd.h... yes
checking for resolv.h... yes
checking for signal.h... yes
checking for stdarg.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking for sysexits.h... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking for sys/mount.h... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/statfs.h... yes
checking for sys/statvfs.h... yes
checking for sys/vfs.h... yes
checking for sys/sysexits.h... no
checking for sys/varargs.h... no
checking for sys/wait.h... yes
checking for sys/loadavg.h... no
checking for termios.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for unix.h... no
checking for utime.h... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking for sys/ipc.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for assert.h... (cached) yes
checking for fopencookie... yes
checking for broken getcwd... no
checking for broken libc stdio... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for struct tm.tm_zone... yes
checking for missing declarations of reentrant functions... done
checking for fclose declaration... ok
checking for tm_gmtoff in struct tm... yes
checking for struct flock... yes
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking size of size_t... 8
checking size of long long... 8
checking size of long long int... 8
checking size of long... 8
checking size of int... 4
checking size of intmax_t... 8
checking size of ssize_t... 8
checking size of ptrdiff_t... 8
checking size of short... 2
checking size of int... (cached) 4
checking size of long... (cached) 8
checking size of long long... (cached) 8
checking for int8... no
checking for int16... no
checking for int32... no
checking for int64... no
checking for int8_t... yes
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for uint8... no
checking for uint16... no
checking for uint32... no
checking for uint64... no
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for u_int8_t... yes
checking for u_int16_t... yes
checking for u_int32_t... yes
checking for u_int64_t... yes
checking for __builtin_expect... yes
checking for __builtin_clz... yes
checking for __builtin_ctzl... yes
checking for __builtin_ctzll... yes
checking for struct stat.st_blksize... yes
checking for struct stat.st_blocks... yes
checking for struct stat.st_rdev... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_storage... yes
checking for field sa_len in struct sockaddr... no
checking for IPv6 support... yes
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking for alphasort... yes
checking for asctime_r... yes
checking for chroot... yes
checking for ctime_r... yes
checking for cuserid... yes
checking for crypt... no
checking for flock... yes
checking for ftok... yes
checking for funopen... no
checking for gai_strerror... yes
checking for gcvt... yes
checking for getloadavg... yes
checking for getlogin... yes
checking for getprotobyname... yes
checking for getprotobynumber... yes
checking for getservbyname... yes
checking for getservbyport... yes
checking for gethostname... (cached) yes
checking for getrusage... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for gmtime_r... yes
checking for getpwnam_r... yes
checking for getgrnam_r... yes
checking for getpwuid_r... yes
checking for grantpt... yes
checking for inet_ntoa... yes
checking for inet_ntop... yes
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for isascii... yes
checking for link... yes
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for lockf... yes
checking for lchown... yes
checking for lrand48... yes
checking for memcpy... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for mkstemp... yes
checking for mmap... yes
checking for nl_langinfo... yes
checking for perror... yes
checking for poll... yes
checking for ptsname... yes
checking for putenv... yes
checking for realpath... yes
checking for random... yes
checking for rand_r... yes
checking for scandir... yes
checking for setitimer... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for localeconv... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for setpgid... yes
checking for setsockopt... yes
checking for setvbuf... yes
checking for shutdown... yes
checking for sin... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for srand48... yes
checking for srandom... yes
checking for statfs... yes
checking for statvfs... yes
checking for std_syslog... no
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strcoll... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strftime... yes
checking for strnlen... yes
checking for strptime... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for strtok_r... yes
checking for symlink... yes
checking for tempnam... yes
checking for tzset... yes
checking for unlockpt... yes
checking for unsetenv... yes
checking for usleep... yes
checking for utime... yes
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking for vasprintf... yes
checking for asprintf... yes
checking for nanosleep... yes
checking for nanosleep in -lrt... yes
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking for __sync_fetch_and_add... yes
checking for strlcat... no
checking for strlcpy... no
checking for getopt... yes
checking for utime.h... (cached) yes
checking whether utime accepts a null argument... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for declared timezone... yes
checking for type of reentrant time-related functions... POSIX
checking for readdir_r... yes
checking for type of readdir_r... POSIX
checking for in_addr_t... yes
checking for crypt_r... no

[1mGeneral settings[0;10m
checking whether to include gcov symbols... no
checking whether to include debugging symbols... no
checking layout of installed files... PHP
checking path to configuration file... DEFAULT
checking where to scan for configuration files... 
checking whether to enable PHP's own SIGCHLD handler... no
checking whether to explicitly link against libgcc... no
checking whether to enable short tags by default... yes
checking whether to enable dmalloc... no
checking whether to enable IPv6 support... yes
checking whether to enable DTrace support... no
checking how big to make fd sets... using system default

[1mConfiguring extensions[0;10m
checking size of long... (cached) 8
checking size of int... (cached) 4
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for strtoll... yes
checking for atoll... yes
checking for strftime... (cached) yes
checking whether to enable LIBXML support... yes
checking libxml2 install dir... no
checking for xml2-config path... /usr/bin/xml2-config
checking whether libxml build works... yes
checking for OpenSSL support... yes
checking for Kerberos support... no
checking whether to use system default cipher list instead of hardcoded value...
 no
checking for RAND_egd... no
checking for pkg-config... no
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries
**ERROR** Could not configure PHP build
```

Comment: When you say you installed OpenSSL, did you install `libssl-dev` from Ubuntu? Or are you doing something else, like building OpenSSL from sources? (When I performed the formatting edit, I changed "OpenSSL" to "libssl-dev" because you were calling out packages and libraries. Also see questions like [How do I install and build against OpenSSL 1.0.0 on Ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3153114)).

Comment: It looks like the wrong `confg.log` was displayed (maybe the top level one). There should be a test shown prior to ***`configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries`***. Can you `find $PWD -name 'config.log'` and add the failed test from the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install these package in order to proceed :

```
apt-get install build-essential libexpat1-dev libgeoip-dev libpng-dev libpcre3-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev rcs zlib1g-dev libmcrypt-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libwebp-dev pkg-config
```