# filesystem location and compile with md5 under linux?

Tags: md5

I am running stock linux gnome ubuntu 13.10.  A locate from the cli tells me the md5.h file is at

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-32-generic/include/config/crypto/md5.h
```

but most examples here tell me to include an openssl .h file.  simply put, what header file should I include in the C file to have my program compile under most linux installations (and how do I invoke gcc to find it; does it need a library link)?

thanks.

Comment: That header is part of the kernel. It's only useful if you are developing a kernel module that needs MD5. You are probably looking for a user space library like openssl. If you are concerned that it won't be available on a particular system you can always link it statically.

Answer (score 0):

ok, the kernel md5 module does not seem to be available to outside use.  so, for end user application, this one requires a ubuntu install not only of openssl, but of openssl-dev (apt-get install openssl-dev).  once it is installed, -lcrypto will work.  see also

[How do I install the OpenSSL libraries on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016956/how-do-i-install-the-openssl-c-library-on-ubuntu)