# undefined symbol: OPENSSL_sk_num

Tags: python-2.7, pyopenssl, certbot

I'm trying to renew [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate with [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/). It stopped working and i don't know why. Here is the error:

```
ImportError: /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/
hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_sk_num
```

I have newest OpenSSL version installed

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0d  26 Jan 2017
```

I tried debugging this problem by doing the following. First i just tried adding import OpenSSL in python console. It worked perfectly, no errors. But when i try

```
. ~/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/activate
```

Then `>>> import OpenSSl`
I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 12, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_sk_num
```

I tried removing the /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/ path then tried to run certbot-auto again. Still i get the same error. Is there anyone who faced this problem and know the solution? Please help me out here. Need to renew few certificates.

**UPDATE:**

I'v found the problem source that in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory there is an old version of libssl.so.1.0.0 and it doesn't have `OPENSSL_sk_num`. When i try to replace with newer version libssl1.1 (it does have `OPENSSL_sk_num`) then i get an error that it requires `OPENSSL_VERSION 1.0.1`. Then after some struggle deleting libraries from /usr directories and local directories i get error `ImportError: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. How can i change it so letsencrypt uses newer library?

**SOLUTION**

After some struggle. I just reinstalled openssl version 1.1.0c. Copied letsencrypt library from another project and it worked. I think some upgrade ruined it. So i suggest everyone when you are running letsencrypt just use --no-self-upgrade option.

**SOLUTION UPDATE**

After encountered this problem one more time i decided to resolve it the correct way. So basically you need to recompile openssl 1.1.0c with command:

`./config -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,'$(LIBRPATH)'` and `make`

Copy the compiled `libcrypto.so.1.1` and `libssl.so.1.1` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Then you need to redo or just modify `libcrypto` and `libssl` symlinks.
By being in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` folder enter commands `ln -s libssl.so.1.1 libssl` and `ln -s libcrypto.so.1.1 libcrypto`.

Then enter following commands:

```
cd ~/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/
./pip uninstall cryptography pyopenssl -y
./pip install --upgrade pip
rm -rf ~/.cache/
./pip install cryptography pyopenssl
```

And your'e done, everything should work correctly.

Comment: Just a guess, but drop back to OpenSSL 1.0.2 line. A lot of symbols changed in 1.1.0, and some visibility changed. OpenSSL  1.0.2 and OpenSSL 1.1.0 are *not* binary compatible.

Comment: I don't know how to completely delete the new version from distribution. Because i have deleted everything i found with command whereis openssl. Then ran command apt-get remove openssl. Then just installed with apt-get install openssl. Now my version is OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 still can't renew. Any ideas?

Comment: @ŽygimantasBaranauskas Is it still the same error?

Comment: @glibdud Yes error is still the same. Nothing changed.

Comment: Looks like there's a [related issue](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/1646) on certbot's github.

Comment: @glibdud Tried every solution. Nothing helps. I don't know what they mean about libssl-dev. How can i install it matching?

Comment: *" I don't know what they mean about libssl-dev. How can i install it matching..."* - See [How do I install the OpenSSL libraries on Ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3016956/608639)

Comment: @jww Tried it yum doesn't have any repos in ubuntu somehow.. This is bumming  me out.

Comment: @jww - I found kind of problem source. It's the library in directory lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. When i try to replace it with newer version of libssl then error is changing to OPENSSL_VERSION1.0.1 not the SUM one. Is there any way to change default libssl that letsencrypt is using? LD_PATH_LIBRARY how to change it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like in version 1.1.0f of openssl the symbol `OPENSSL_sk_num` has moved to `libcrypto.a`. The build of python 3 didn't seem to link that in, hence the missing symbol. However, I was mistaken. When the file `Modules/Setup.dist` is modified to pick up your own version of openssl, you need to copy it to `Modules/Setup`, otherwise it will use the already installed ssl.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the `undefined symbol: OPENSSL_sk_num` error after compiling openssl myself.
I could solve the problem by removing the openssl directory in`~/.local/share` which was created erlier and starting over. It has to be some caching and/or wrong library path issue.

Answer (score 0):

I met this error when install Python3.6.2 on Centos 7 ,it has been intalled openssl 1.0.1e,and I download openssl 1.1.0.e. after next steps it works correctly.

```
cd ${openssl_src_path}
```

in my case ${openssl_src_path} is '/usr/local/server/openssl-1.1.0e'

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl

make
make test
make install
```

after OpenSSL installed correctly, install Python3.6.2

```
cd ${python_src_path}/Modules
```

modify 'Setup' file ,change log :

```
    SSL=/usr/local/openssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I/usr/local/openssl/include -I/usr/local/openssl/include/openssl \
    -L/usr/local/openssl/lib -lssl -lcryptoere
```

> 'SSL=/usr/local/openssl' is value of install OpenSSL parameter '--openssldir' .and make sure DUSE_SSL directory exist.

```
cd ${python_src_path}
./configure
make
make install
```

hope it help.