# Compiling C program with OpenSSL

Tags: c, compilation, openssl

I am new to Openssl. I have openssl 1.1.0e and libssl-dev installed on ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to run the example on this page in openssl documentation
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html.

I use the command

```
gcc example1.c -lssl -lcrypto
```

to compile the program. But I get the following error
[Undefined Reference error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjdkj.png)

I have seen related questions on the forum but cannot find the solution. If anyone can help with pointing out the solution, it will be a great help.

Comment: post your code in text here.  don't use links to images that contain text.

Comment: Btw, I have compiled openssl code with exactly the gcc flags you used.

Comment: Ubuntu ships with OpenSSL 1.0.2 (or maybe 1.0.1); not OpenSSL 1.1.0. You need to use `-L`, too. `-L` tells the linker where to find the libraries. You might find it easier to use Ubuntu's OpenSSL since everything will be on-path. Also see [How do I install the OpenSSL libraries on Ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3016956/608639)

Comment: #include <openssl/evp.h>

Comment: @jww thanks for comment it worked after using the default OpenSSL 1.0.0

Comment: post the actual code YOU are using, post the actual error messages your compiler is outputing.  DO NOT post links to that information.

Comment: Note: when compiling with `gcc`, at a minimum use the following parameters to enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11 )