# Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder

Tags: github, cmake, openssl

I extracted **Cmake** zip file (downloaded from github) and tried to install it but an error occured.
I tried installing **OpenSSL** and tried to install  Cmake but Error(same) is still comming

Terminal output is below :

```
CMake 3.16.20191118, Copyright 2000-2019 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc   
C++ compiler on this system is: g++    
Makefile processor on this system is: make
g++ has setenv
g++ has unsetenv
g++ does not have environ in stdlib.h
g++ has stl wstring
g++ has <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
---------------------------------------------
make: 'cmake' is up to date.
loading initial cache file /root/Cmake/Bootstrap.cmk/InitialCacheFlags.cmake
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/Cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/Cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Problem while running initial CMake
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake not able to find OpenSSL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248775/cmake-not-able-to-find-openssl-library)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today trying to compile cmake 3.16-rc4 under Ubuntu 18.04. While trying to fix that by setting appropriate paths and looking for them in the first place, I discovered this: [How do I install the OpenSSL libraries on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016956/how-do-i-install-the-openssl-libraries-on-ubuntu)

So the solution is to simply do:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

So cmake obviously needs the dev package of openssl. Kudos to [Niki Yoshiuchi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117539/niki-yoshiuchi), who has given the desired answer in the linked question.