# openssl/bio.h file not found

Tags: go, openssl

I got This error When I run my go project, and use openssl library
[image]

Comment: Can you please paste the text in the image instead of image itself? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the openssl libraries.

- Linux: it's `libssl-dev` (see [How do I install the OpenSSL libraries on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016956/how-do-i-install-the-openssl-libraries-on-ubuntu)).
- macOS: install with `homebrew`: `brew install openssl`. See [the doc for the `github.com/spacemonkeygo/openssl` package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spacemonkeygo/openssl#readme-using-on-macos)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22, default OpenSSL is grater than 3.0,. github.com/spacemonkeygo/openssl require OpenSSL1.1.x

you should need download OpenSSL1.1.x source code and compile it.