# Python interface for openEMS software not installing

Tags: python, installation, terminal, open-source, physics

I am trying to install an open source Maxwell's equations solver known as OpenEMS. To run that software the python interface for two things within it are required to be manually installed through terminal-CSXCAD and openEMS.

To do that I have to go into the python directory within both CSXCAD and the openems directory in terminal and run the command `pip install --user .`. However it is not happening every time I try.

When I try to run it within the CSXCAD python directory it says the following,

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully
```

[image]

And when I try to install the python interface for openems I get the following errors,

```
python setup.py egg_info did not run succesfully
```

[image]

I searched up the problems that were coming such as `python setup.py egg info did not run successfully` for the CSXCAD python interface and `python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully`. I even tried upgrading `pip` and `setuptools` but nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

The header files for libraries like CSXCAD are usually packaged into a different distribution, generally identified by `*-devel` or `*-dev` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2358835/10659910) for more details). It looks like you need to install `csxcad-devel` or the equivalent for your system.

The second error appears to be due to a version issue with your Cython installation, I would recommend updating Cython and if that doesn't work then check the OpenEMS documentation to find the supported version(s) of Cython and make sure you have one of those versions installed.