# Unbound module Findlib error during installation of Ocaml Batteries

Tags: debian, ocaml, ocaml-batteries

I have created my `~/.ocamlinit` as follows

```
let interactive = !Sys.interactive;;
Sys.interactive := false;; (*Pretend to be in non-interactive mode*)
#use "topfind";;
Sys.interactive := interactive;; (*Return to regular interactive mode*)

Toploop.use_silently Format.err_formatter (Filename.concat (Findlib.package_directory "batteries") "battop.ml");;
```

When I type `ocaml` at command line, I get the following error:

```
$ ocaml
        Objective Caml version 3.12.1

Cannot find file topfind.
File ".ocamlinit", line 6, characters 60-85:
Error: Unbound module Findlib
#
```

What is causing this issue and how should I go about for fixing this issue?

(I am on Debian Wheezy)

Edit: I have set an alias for ocaml:

```
alias ocaml='rlwrap -H /home/nanda/.ocaml_history -D 2 -i -s 10000 ocaml'
```

Comment: It might be helpful to first check if `#use "topfind";;` works when the toploop has been started without your `.ocamlinit`.

Comment: @dkim: Strange! I checked and that does not work either.

Comment: Did you install the `ocaml-findlib` package? http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ocaml-findlib

Comment: Yes I installed it, sorry to not have mentioned it. I just added a statement to print "TESTING" in the .ocamlinit and I could see it above the "cannot find the file topfind" part.

Comment: How about `libfindlib-ocaml-dev`?

Comment: That did the trick!! Thank you so much. I am not sure why a dev package would be required. Any insight in this regard?

Comment: A library usually consists of two packages, one for runtime and another for development files. [What do the *-dev packages in the Linux package repositories actually contain?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1157192/234658)

Comment: In this case, the `/usr/lib/ocaml/topfind` file that the `#use "topfind";;` directive searches for turns out to be included in the `libfindlib-ocaml-dev` package.

Comment: I ought to search for topfind using apt-file before, but somehow it didnt register to me that topfind, a module, is actually a file. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With due thanks to `dkim`, I would post the solution that worked for me. Hope this helps someone else.

#### Ocaml Batteries Installation Process

To be able to work with the ocaml-batteries-included, I followed this process:

```
sudo apt-get install ocaml ocaml-batteries-included ocaml-doc ledit rlwrap
```

`rlwrap` or `ledit` is needed to add readline support for OCaml toploop.

Added an alias in `.bashrc`, to save the commands entered in the ocaml toploop.

```
 alias ocaml='rlwrap -H /home/nanda/.ocaml_history -D 2 -i -s 10000 ocaml'
```

-H specifies history file name
-D ignores duplicates
-i case insensitive
-s limits the number of commands stored in this file

As mentioned in the comments, I was receiving this error when trying to invoke the ocaml interpreter.

```
$ ocaml
        Objective Caml version 3.12.1

Cannot find file topfind.
File ".ocamlinit", line 6, characters 60-85:
Error: Unbound module Findlib
#
```

I received this error because ocaml-findlib package was not properly installed. I have mamaged to solve this by installing the `libfindlib-ocaml-dev` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libfindlib-ocaml-dev
```

For some people, the issue is solved when findlib package is installed from sources as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/issues/140)

Some more helpful links:

1. http://mirror.ocamlcore.org/wiki.cocan.org/tips_for_using_the_ocaml_toplevel.html
2. http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.2.1/doc/guide-html/quickstart.html
3. http://www.donadeo.net/post/2010/installing-batteries