# Is there cpm like npm or apt-get?

Tags: c

I'v been use some module manager like npm for node.js or apt-get in ubuntu, I find it's really easy to build more. And I just want to know is there a cpm for module manage in c programming?

Comment: C modules are called *libraries* and you can use [apt-get to install development packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157192/) to compile code that uses the libraries.  You link with a library after installing it with `-l` in gcc-compatible compilers.  I'd leave a more detailed answer but I'm not near a debian-based OS at the moment.

Comment: @indiv Thanks for you comment. I know the libraries, but it's not cross platform and not convenient to use. I usually have no idea about which library is popular or suitable. I'm just curious if there is a cpm which can search module or library, and take them into my project easily.

Comment: well you can do a cpm, with a configure and install script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clib` may be the answer. https://github.com/clibs/clib 
it is proposed to offer some stand-alone "micro c libraries".