# luarocks lyaml installation error

Tags: lua, luarocks

on `luarocks install lyaml` I get following error:

`Error: Could not find expected file libyaml.a, or libyaml.so, or libyaml.so.* for YAML -- you may have to install YAML in your system and/or pass YAML_DIR or YAML_LIBDIR to the luarocks command. Example: luarocks install lyaml YAML_DIR=/usr/local`

lua version: 5.1.5

How do I install YAML in system to start using lyaml rock?

Comment: What OS are you using? It should just be a matter of manually installing libyaml first, and then setting the path to that installed library with the YAML_DIR luarocks parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you get a LuaRocks message saying `you may have to install ____ in your system` it means the rockspec has an [external dependency](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Paths-and-external-dependencies).

#### Installing external dependencies

The way to satisfy this dependency is to install the package using the appropriate means of your system: if using Debian/Ubuntu, with `apt-get`, if using macOS, probably using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), etc.

Note that for building code, in systems that have the concept of [dev packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157192/what-do-the-dev-packages-in-the-linux-package-repositories-actually-contain), such as most Linux distributions, you need to install both the main library package and the dev package (which contains the header files for compilation). For example, for Debian/Ubuntu, to satisfy this dependency you need to run `apt-get install libyaml libyaml-dev`.

Unfortunately, the names are not fully consistent across systems and distros: a module may be called `ncurses-dev` in one system, `libncurses6w-dev` in another, etc. So in your particular case you'll have to search around for the right name of the YAML library (the package providing libyaml) in your system.

#### Once the external dependency is installed...

Installing a library with the system package manager will usually install the necessary files in locations that are automatically detected by LuaRocks, so running

`luarocks install lyaml`

again should find the libyaml files and proceed with the installation.

#### If external dependencies are installed in a non-standard location

If that fails, you can find the directories where the library (`libyaml.so`) and header (`yaml.h`) were installed and tell LuaRocks about it. For example, if libyaml.so was installed in some non-standard locations such as `/opt/lib/yaml/libyaml.so` and the header in `/opt/include/yaml-1/yaml.h` you would do this:

`luarocks install lyaml YAML_LIBDIR=/opt/lib/yaml/ YAML_INCDIR=/opt/include/yaml-1/`

This kind of situation happens when a system installs headers or libraries in a subdirectory. For example, for LuaSec on the Mac, which uses OpenSSL, it is sometimes necessary to use pathnames like this:

`luarocks install luasec OPENSSL_INCDIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include OPENSSL_LIBDIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`