# No line history / autocomplete available in python REPL

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, libreadline

I downloaded and compiled Python 3.7 from source on a Debian machine, however the 'readline' functionality (viewing line history, tab to autocomplete) is missing. I have the `python3.5` package which was installed using `apt`, and the functionality works there. I have the `libreadline7` and `readline-common` packages installed (these were installed before I compiled Python 3.7). I'm guessing there's a config file I need to edit / create somewhere, or maybe a flag I need to use during compilation? All the answers I could find lead to "install the `readline` package" which was already the case for me.

Output of `./configure | grep "readline"` during Python compilation:

```
checking how to link readline libs... none
checking for rl_pre_input_hook in -lreadline... no
checking for rl_completion_display_matches_hook in -lreadline... no
checking for rl_resize_terminal in -lreadline... no
checking for rl_completion_matches in -lreadline... no
checking for append_history in -lreadline... no
```

Comment: I don't recall having to configure anything last time I compiled Python - once I had readline installed, the build process would automatically pick it up and include it in the Python build.

Comment: Try recompiling Python and grepping the build output to search for the string `readline`.

Comment: Also, what happens if you do `import readline`?

Comment: @user2357112 Question updated, good suggestion. Seems like the `configure` script can't find a readline package. `python3.7: import readline` gives `ModuleNotFoundError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are missing [`libreadline-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libreadline-dev) which contains the actual header files that are needed to compile against the readline library.

If you `sudo apt install libreadline-dev` and then recompile your python, you'll get readline support.

Answering your comment about what are header files: Header files are a component of C and C++ libraries. They declare which functions are available in a library. The standard Python implementation is written in C and thus uses these header files to declare the existence of these functions. By default `configure` uses the presence of these headers files with matching function names to determine the presence of readline and other library functionality. Thus the `configure` script outputs `no` saying you are missing this critical functionality of readline. That's the indication that readline is "missing" on your system for the purposes of compilation. The reason Debian splits off header files into a separate package is that not everyone compiles code from scratch on Debian, so `-dev` packages contain the *dev* depdendencies for a library. You only need to install `-dev` packages if you are doing development *against* that library. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157192/what-do-the-dev-packages-in-the-linux-package-repositories-actually-contain) may also be relevant to your follow on question.

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify what 'header files' are and why they come as part of the `-dev` version of the package?

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I found this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/install-python-370-on-ubuntu-1804debian-95 which also recommends installing `libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev build-essential zlib1g`