# make: *** [Makefile:1280: install] Error 1

Tags: installation, makefile

OS Ubuntu 20.04.3
Python intalation 3.10.2
error: make: *** [Makefile:1280: install] Erro 1 after sudo make install
make: latest version
what should I do?

Comment: You should look earlier than the last line to find the real error.  That message is just make telling you that something went wrong.  If you want to know WHAT went wrong, look for the earlier error messages.  When building code it's virtually always the case that the FIRST errors are the most important and they get progressively more useless as they go, and the last message is likely the least important.  If you don't understand the first errors, then please edit your question to add proper formatting and _cut and paste_ the compile command and the first few errors.

Comment: Ok. Accordingly with the ubuntu command prompt I've got python 3.10.2 installed. I'm a windows  user also and thought that IDLE would come along with tha package for Python 3.10. I'm kind of stuck, because the Python version used by IDLE is attached to Python 3.9. Could you help me to update it to Python 3.10.2?

Comment: I don't do Windows, I only work with GNU/Linux.  But, I don't know why you're jumping to the conclusion that the problem is the version of Python.  Do you have any reason to believe that?  I recommend, as I said above, that you _edit your question_ and include the actual error messages you see, so others can see them as well.  And, if the error messages do indicate it's a Python issue, you probably want to update the tags on your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

This is the full set of steps which worked for me. to install

```
# python3 --version
Python 3.10.4
```

In Ubuntu 21.10:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential
$ sudo apt install libssl-dev libffi-dev libncurses5-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev libbz2-dev libsqlite3-dev make gcc
$ cd /to/extracted/folder
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

**Common errors if you do not follow this process:**

*Critical dependencies were missing:*

```
[Makefile:1280: install] Erro 1
```

*Ran 'make' before all dependencies were met but it didn't fail to compile (have to install all packages then make clean then make):*

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting <package>
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/<package>/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package> (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for <package>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to install [dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157192/what-do-the-dev-packages-in-the-linux-package-repositories-actually-contain) (libraries) to be able build `python` from source code:

```sh
sudo apt install libssl-dev libffi-dev libncurses5-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev libbz2-dev libsqlite3-dev make gcc
```