# FFmpeg build error pkg-config can't find x265 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnuma: No such file or directory

Tags: ffmpeg, compilation, pkg-config, bug-reporting, libx265

I am trying to build ffmpeg with custom libraries from source code.

Every package in my script builds as it should but when it gets time to run the ffmpeg build using all of the packages it fails with a weird error code shown at the bottom of the ffmpeg build log.

```
BEGIN /home/jman/tmp/ffconf.JouXp6kg/test.c
    1   #include <x265.h>
    2   #include <stdint.h>
    3   long check_x265_api_get(void) { return (long) x265_api_get; }
    4   int main(void) { int ret = 0;
    5    ret |= ((intptr_t)check_x265_api_get) & 0xFFFF;
    6   return ret; }
END /home/jman/tmp/ffconf.JouXp6kg/test.c
gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -DPIC -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include/lilv-0 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -std=c11 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -pthread -DLILV_STATIC -DSRATOM_STATIC -DSORD_STATIC -DSERD_STATIC -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include/lilv-0 -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include/sratom-0 -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include/sord-0 -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include/serd-0 -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include/opus -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include/opus -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include/srt -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include/svt-av1 -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -I/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -c -o /home/jman/tmp/ffconf.JouXp6kg/test.o /home/jman/tmp/ffconf.JouXp6kg/test.c
gcc -L/home/jman/Documents/ffmpeg-build/workspace/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,noexecstack -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o /home/jman/tmp/ffconf.JouXp6kg/test /home/jman/tmp/ffconf.JouXp6kg/test.o -lx265 -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lgcc_s -lgcc -lrt -ldl -lnuma -ldl -lpthread -lm -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnuma: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: x265 not found using pkg-config
```

Does anyone know what this `-lnuma` is referring to?

I had no issues just a few days ago when I last ran my build script and then all of a sudden this issue appeared.

This is my build script in its entirety: [FFmpeg-build.sh](https://github.com/slyfox1186/ffmpeg-build-script/blob/master/scripts/build-ffmpeg)

Update: Per Allan Winds' instructions here is the output of:

`find /usr/lib -name libnuma\* -ls`

```
  4987897     48 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        48152 Mar 24  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1.0.0
  4992286     76 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        77086 Mar 24  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.a
  4987896      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Dec 29 12:03 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 -> libnuma.so.1.0.0
  4992287      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Mar 24  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so -> libnuma.so.1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It means your build failed when it's trying to link the `numa` library.  The linker will search for the library using built-in paths along with the ones specified with -L.  Specifically, -lnuma will search for libnuma.a and libnuma.so (per man ld(1)).  The symlink link from the libnuma.so to the actual library ships libnuma-dev package.  You install the package with:

```
sudo apt install libnuma-dev
```

The -dev package depends on the libnuma1 which is the actual library.  You can, if you want, specify the versioned library directly with `-l:libnuma.so.1` instead of `-lnuma`.

Comment: It was the libnuma-dev that was required! Thanks!

Comment: Add the output of `find /usr/lib -name libnuma\* -ls` to your question.  On my system it's in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1.0.0, and you include that search path with the `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.  Also retry after you rebuild the cache with `sudo ldconfig -v`.

Comment: Allan, I believe my file is found `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnma.so.0` I thought the dev libraries were `name.0` and the bare bones run packages `are name.0.0`. Is that right? I am getting my info from this post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157192/what-do-the-dev-packages-in-the-linux-package-repositories-actually-contain`

Comment: @slyfox1186 Great job on providing the additional details.  I updated answer with our findings and hopefully answered your remaining question.